# Can't figure out how to make this circle a ring

Tags: modeling

I just started using Blender today.

I am trying to make a 3d render for my community's logo to use for animation and I need to figure out how to make the ring. So far I haven't been able to find anything to fix this. I hope someone here is able to help with this problem.

[image: Here is what its supposed to look like]

[image: Need to find a way to add a hole to this circle.]

Comment: press "i" to inset, then delete the inner circle (X > Faces). If you need to extrude, press E and extrude

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the solution that moonboots proposed, it's easily done in two steps:

1. Press <kbd>I</kbd> to **inset** the face. Move the mouse until the inner circle has the desired width of the ring. Left-click or <kbd>Return</kbd> to confirm the action.

[image: inset1]

2. After insetting, the inner circle is automatically selected. Press <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>Del</kbd> and choose *Faces* from the *Delete* options.

[image: inset2]

And you're finished! Insetting is always a good tool if you want to create contours like that, especially on shapes that are more irregular than a square or circle, because extrude and scale usually doesn't work well if not all vertices have even distances from the center of scaling.

[image: inset_result]

Comment: ohhhhhhhhh ok! that worked! ill remember that. made this so much easier

Comment: @JohnMarkCardullo And especially it's helpful for not so regular symmetrical shapes. Please read this: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution, step by step.

So if you are here:

[image: circle with face in edit mode]

- press <kbd>x</kbd>. This will bring up a menu:

[image: delete menu]

- select *Only Faces*.
- tap <kbd>a</kbd> to select all again

[image]

- tap <kbd>e</kbd> to extrude followed by <kbd>s</kbd> to scale and move your mouse.  Moving towards the center scales inward, moving away scales outward.
- when you had the size ring you want click the left mouse button to complete the operation.

This is the result:

[image: ring]